# What does Kolmogov-Smirnov tells us when the p value is high?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have a dataset which seems to be uniform by eye-examination.

I want to verify if this distribution is indeed uniform. I saw a [couple of questions](https:///questions/530771/hypothesis-testing-to-check-if-a-distribution-is-uniform) in here which suggested using a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test on my data set, so I decided to [read about this test online.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test)

According to Wikipedia, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests the null hypothesis:

**$H_0$:  the sample is drawn from the reference distribution**

I performed a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test on my dataset [using R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dgof/versions/1.4/topics/ks.test) and **obtained a p value of 0.63**.

Now here is my question: Since this p value is high ($\geq 0.05$), I cannot refute the null hypothesis. **Does this mean I accept the null hypothesis as true or does it only mean that I cannot refute it?**

If the latter, is there any test for the hypothesis:

**$H_0$:  the sample does NOT come from a uniform distribution**

so that I can be sure that my distribution is indeed uniform?

Just to be clear: I am interested in proving a **positive** result: That the distribution IS indeed uniform.

Comment: This is a general question about hypothesis testing.  You can find (many) answers by reading our posts about that subject and about interpreting p-values.  One special concern in this case is that often people abuse the KS test by fitting the distribution to the data and then using the fit for the reference.  This *hugely* increases the p-value.  Thus, an alternative conclusion to your first question is "because the p-value is high, don't conclude anything until you are sure you applied the test correctly."

Comment: @whuber, can you elaborate on what do you mean by 'sure you applied the test correctly'? I understand I can't conclude that my distribution is uniform with a high p value, but what are my alternatives?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Test_with_estimated_parameters.  Good alternatives include the chi-squared test.